# Slashes in a query string parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

How can I send a file path as a query string parameter?

This is my string parameter:

> //domain/documents/Pdf/1234.pdf

I have tried that:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("documents/print/{filePath*}")]
    public string PrintDocuments([FromBody] string[] docs,string filePath)
    {
       .....
    }
```

But this is not working, I guess because of the double slashes in the beginning of the parameter.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you not just encode the file path?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If, like you say, that entire string is the parameter, and not a route, you will need to URL encode it. You should always do this anyway:

```
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(<your string>);
// %2F%2Fdomain%2Fdocuments%2FPdf%2F1234.pdf
```

> Update

Since that is not working, I would suggest you Base64 encode it instead of URL encode it:

```
var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(<your string>);
var encodedFilePath = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
```

..and in your controller decode it:

```
byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(filepath);
string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
```

Comment: Thank you, would you be able to give me an example of how to do it?

Comment: I would if I weren't on my phone at the moment. Check out the mvc urlhelper . I would avoid system.web if possible.

Comment: Thank you! 1-I tried that but i'm getting a 404 error, this is my URL: http://localhost:111/MySolution/api/documents/print/%5C%5Cdomain%5Cdocuments%5CPdf%2F1234.pdf ,Any idea how to solve that? 2-would you be able to explain why you would avoid system.web? Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't know why you get 404. Are you sure your route is configured correctly? Did you try a normal string as a test instead of one that is a  file path? System.Web is a heavy, bloated, legacy library that is not necessarily needed with MVC. If you already have a reference to it for another reason then it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I tried with a regular string and it worked fine, it's the '%' signs that cause it, i'm not sure what to do about it. Thank you!

Comment: I guess it is still interpreting the route parameter as part of the route. See my edit for use of Base64 encoding.

Comment: Thank you, but do you know how to use Base64 in JavaScript, I'm calling the API from js.

Comment: Not offhand, but you can ask the Google.

Comment: When encoding it with %2F it still is removed in the input string variable in your GET controller method.

Comment: I think that easier way is just to use `[HttpPost]` method with the model class and `filepath` property inside (i.e. instead of use `Route` ), especially since you're sending a request to print

Comment: @Damilinks that is javascript, the question is about server-side with .NET

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Web.HTTPUtility.UrlEncode(@"//domain/documents/Pdf/1234.pdf")
```