# Http request with string containing blanks and '/'

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, asp.net-core, httprequest

I have a controller as the following below:

```
using CadastroDerivativos.Domain.Interfaces.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace CadastroDerivativos.WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/equity")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EquityOptController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IEquityOptService _equityOptService;

        public EquityOptController(IEquityOptService equityOptService)
        {
            _equityOptService = equityOptService;
        }

        [HttpGet("{ticker}")]
        public bool CheckTicker(string ticker)
        {
            return _equityOptService.hasTicker(ticker);
        }
    }
}
```

I can send a http request with the following url: `https://localhost:44353/api/equity/ewz%20us%20-12-2021%20C41`.

[image: request with postman]

The problem is that I need to receive in my controller a string like the following: `EWZ US 12/21/21 C41 Equity`, completely as I passed it would be ideal. So, how can I pass a string like the one in the http request? I'm using the get method, is it the one I should use?

**EDIT**

When I try to make the request with this url: `https://localhost:44353/api/equity/ewz%20us%12/21/21%20C4`1, I believe that the `/` of the date are interpreted as separating the url, causing that it is not possible to call the service on the backend.

Comment: What's wrong with the way you showing in the post? Can you please [edit] the question to show how you would like to call the service?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slashes in a query string parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119748/slashes-in-a-query-string-parameter)

Comment: I would use another separator for the datetime string, otherwise you can only rely on the catch-all wild-card like `{*ticker}` but you should find more about it before using (such as for potential issues).

Comment: 2 things... 1st you need to encode the URL to be able to use '/' with %2F (check this site https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) 2nd on backend site use WebUtility.UrlDecode(ticker) to decode '%2F' back to '/'